# Javascript - Play/ Pause button for video

Tags: javascript, html

For my university work I have to make video controls and I'm trying to implement a play/pause button to start with but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<script src="Scripts/VideoScript.js"></script>
<section id="Example_Video_Container">
    <video width = 576 height = 432 id = "Example_Video">  
        <source src="Videos/Example_Video.mp4">
        <source src="Videos/Example_Video.webm">
    </video>
    <div id="Example_Video_Controls">
        <button type="button" id="Play_Pause" >Play</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener (“DOMContentLoaded”,handleWindowLoad) 
function handleWindowLoad ()
{
    var Video = document.getElementById ( "Example_Video" );
    var PlayButton = document.getElementById ( "Play_Pause" );
    var MuteButton = document.getElementById ( "Mute_Unmute" );
    var Slider = document.getElementById ( "Slider" );

    PlayButton.addEventListener ( "click", Play_Pause_Video ) ;

    function Play_Pause_Video ()
    {
        if (Video.paused === true)
        {
            Video.play();
            PlayButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        }
        else
        {
            Video.pause();
            PlayButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked my file paths too, they should be all ok.

Comment: html5 video tag provides it's own controls.  `<video width = 576 height = 432 id = "Example_Video" controls>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [play pause html5 video javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327907/play-pause-html5-video-javascript)

Comment: Notice the `“` in `window.addEventListener (“DOMContentLoaded”,handleWindowLoad) `. It is not the actual `"` that javascript recognizes. Replace it with `"`.

Comment: Please see my answer @Will

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and that also worked, very easy fix thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console for errors.  I noticed one -

```
Javascript Error: 'missing ) after argument list"
```

To get around that, replace window.addEventListener()

with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    handleWindowLoad();
});
```

Comment: i tried that and nothing happened, did it work for you?

Comment: oh it does work when i copied that, thanks very much :)

Comment: see my answer @JordanMcArdle

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsc9u99/)

Your code was working perfectly. you was getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in the browser console, which was due to the `“`.

Notice the `“` in `window.addEventListener (“DOMContentLoaded”,handleWindowLoad)` . It is not the actual `"` that javascript recognizes. Replace it with `"`. Thus the JS code would be like

```
window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded",handleWindowLoad);
function handleWindowLoad ()
{
    var Video = document.getElementById ( "Example_Video" );
    var PlayButton = document.getElementById ( "Play_Pause" );
    var MuteButton = document.getElementById ( "Mute_Unmute" );
    var Slider = document.getElementById ( "Slider" );

    PlayButton.addEventListener ( "click", Play_Pause_Video ) ;

    function Play_Pause_Video ()
    {
        if (Video.paused === true)
        {
            Video.play();
            PlayButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        }
        else
        {
            Video.pause();
            PlayButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 contains a built-in attribute for video controls.

Look at this page for help: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_controls.asp

Comment: i know i can just add "controls" to the video tag but the task is to make my own

Answer (score 0):

Code is technically correct and it should work fine, but there is one little mistake.

```
21:17:37.737 SyntaxError: illegal character1 VideoScript.js:1:26
```

In your VideoScript.js, 26th character is illegal at line 1.

```
window.addEventListener (“DOMContentLoaded”,handleWindowLoad)
```

remove this weird double quotes (**“ ”**) and replace it with normal ones (**" "**) and it will work fine :)

```
window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded",handleWindowLoad)
```

This is why you should use debugging tools.

Here is some tips to find out small mistakes like that:

- If you use FireFox click Ctrl+Shift+J and open Browser Console window;
- Refresh your tab where your problematic HTML file is loaded;
- Check Browser Console and you will see if there is any error;
- Copy error and Google it.