# html5-video by button $(...).play is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I try to play videos one after the other via button or automatically at the end of the video.
by this code:

```
//automatically play
$("#videoPlayer").bind('ended', function() {
if(cnt <= 10 && bNum == 0) cnt++;
$('#videoPlayer').attr('poster','./media/spot'+cnt+'.jpg').html('<source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.ogg" type="video/ogg"><source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.webm" type="video/webm">');
$('#video-title').html('Spot '+cnt);
if(cnt < 10) {
  this.load();
  this.play();
  cnt++;
}
bNum = 1;
if(cnt >= 10) $('.link1').remove();
});

//Play by the button
$('.link1').on('click', function() {
  if(cnt < 10 && bNum == 0) cnt++;
  $(this).attr('rel', cnt).attr('title', 'Spot '+cnt);
  $('#videoPlayer').attr('poster','./media/spot'+cnt+'.jpg').html('<source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.ogg" type="video/ogg"><source src="./media/spot'+cnt+'.webm" type="video/webm">');
  $('#video-title').html('Spot '+cnt);
  if(cnt >= 10) $('.link1').remove();
  if(cnt <= 10) {
    if($('#videoPlayer').load()) $('#videoPlayer').play();
    cnt++;
  }
});
```

the html part is:

```
<video width="640" id="videoPlayer" autoplay preload="metadata" poster="./media/spot1.jpg">
<source src="./media/spot1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="./media/spot1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="./media/spot1.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></div>
<ul>
<li class="link1" rel="2">Nächster Spot </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

the automatic part works well without an error. But the part by button gets an error at the line;

```
$('#videoPlayer').play();
```

with the message

```
"$(...).play is not a function".
```

I can't find why. (For `this.play()` I can also write `$('videoPlayer')` in the automatic part. It is the same.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play/pause HTML 5 video using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery)

Answer (score 85):

`$('#videoPlayer')` gives you a jQuery object and the jQuery object does not have a `play` method. The play method you are looking for is in the native dom element inside the jQuery object. To get access to the element inside just use array syntax or `.get()`. e.g. `$('#videoPlayer')[0].play();` or `$('#videoPlayer').get(0).play();`

Comment: That's it! **Thank you very much.** I don't know much enough about this.

Comment: Good grief! Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I found it. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: @Bisneto no one said it did.

Comment: This is your answer: To get access to the element inside just use array syntax or .get(). e.g. $('#videoPlayer')[0].play(); or $('#videoPlayer').get(0).play(). Your answer result: "Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'" . So YOU said. and said WRONG

Comment: @Bisneto this is a jQuery question so `$('#videoPlayer')` gives you a **jQuery** object not an **HTMLElement**. If you're getting an HTMLElement you are doing something wrong.