# Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I spent quite a lot of time trying to figure out why video embedded like here:

```
<video height="256" loop autoplay muted controls id="vid">
         <source type="video/mp4" src="video_file.mp4"></source>
         <source type="video/ogg" src="video_file.ogg"></source>
</video>
```

starts playing automatically once the page is loaded in FireFox but cannot do autoplay in Webkit based browsers. This only happened on some random pages. So far I was unable to find the cause. I suspect some unclosed tags or extensive JS created by CMS editors.

Comment: is it working sometimes ? or not working at all... here is an example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay that i check with chrome, and it works.

Comment: On some pages it is not working at all

Comment: Facing the same issue, worked fine a week ago and without any change it just stopped working. Maybe it's a browser update, very annoying to have to manually play all the video tags via javascript

Comment: Not working for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

The best fix I could get was adding this code just after the `</video>`

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('vid').play();
</script>
```

...not pretty but somehow works.

**UPDATE** 
Recently many browsers can only autoplay the videos with sound off, so you'll need to add `muted` attribute to the video tag too

```
<video autoplay muted>
...
</video>
```

Comment: Or you can code with jQuery `$("videoID").get(0).play();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery

Comment: Or like this:
`$("video[autoplay]").each(function(){ this.play(); });`

Comment: still problem if its not muted https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: this won't work anymore without user interaction AFAIK

Comment: see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone

Comment: works in Chrome 2020 but tbh this hack can be the only  reason chrome should stop invalidating autoplay

Comment: To work on Safari mobile, I also had to include `playsinline`

Comment: autoplay="true"  muted="true" , it works for me, thanks

Comment: Muted somehow works

Comment: `autoplay` works only with `muted`

Answer (score 128):

After using jQuery `play()` or DOM maniupulation as suggested by the other answers, it was not still working (Video wasn't autoplaying) in the Chrome for Android (Version 56.0).

As per this [post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay) in **developers.google.com**, From Chrome 53, the autoplay option is respected by the browser, *if the video is muted*.

So using `autoplay muted` attributes in video tag enables the video to be autoplayed in Chrome browsers from version 53.

Excerpt from the above link:

> Muted autoplay for video is supported by Chrome for Android as of version 53. Playback will start automatically for a video element once it comes into view if both `autoplay` and `muted` are set[...]
>
> ```
> <video autoplay muted>
>     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
>     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
> </video>
> ```
>
> - Muted autoplay is supported by Safari on iOS 10 and later.
> - Autoplay, whether muted or not, is already supported on Android by Firefox and UC Browser: they do not block any kind of autoplay.

Comment: I had this issue in Safari 11 where a background video (no audio) wouldn't play automatically.  Adding `muted` and `autoplay` did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: So why then does autoplay, WITH sound on, work for youtube? It has worked that way since the site's inception.

Answer (score 68):

> Google just changed their policy for autoplay videos, it has to be `muted`

You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

so just add muted

```
<video height="256" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" id="vid" muted>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="video_file.mp4"></source>
         <source type="video/ogg" src="video_file.ogg"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: John Pallett's [comment on the new policy](https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/). He is Google Chrome's Product Manager and _Media Muter_.

Answer (score 33):

It happens that Safari and Chrome on Desktop do not like DOM manipulation around the video tag. They will not fire the play order when the autoplay attribute is set **even** if the canplaythrough event has fired when the DOM around the video tag has changed after initial page load. Basically I had the same issue until I deleted a .wrap() jQuery around the video tag and after that it autoplayed as expected.

Comment: Good call that it doesn't work with .wrap(). However, as far as I can tell, the code needs .get(0) to work: 

    $("#vid").get(0).play();

Comment: @mattsoave `.get(0)` or just `$('#vid')[0].play()`

Comment: Oct 2017, video not autoplaying in spite of attribute in tag is still an issue in Safari.  Using [0].play() as suggested by mattsoave/pmrotule solved the issue.

Answer (score 32):

It worked for me when combined with `muted` attribute

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind it but it works for me!

Comment: correct answer for this question

Comment: THIS! Thank you! Makes sense too! I just wish there was better documentation/logging to indicate that.

Answer (score 30):

For me the issue was that the `muted` attribute needed to be added within the `video` tag. I.e.:

```
<video width="1920" height="1980" src="video/Night.mp4"
type="video/mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay loop
muted></video>`
```

Comment: Works for latest Chrome on Windows8

Comment: On Crome if i add muted disable sound. I don't want this

Answer (score 25):

Chrome does not allow to auto play video with sound on, so make sure to add `muted` attribute to the `video` tag like this

```
<video width="320" height="240"  autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: That doesn't add anything new. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994667/9662601) already mentions this. Also the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42414858/9662601) goes into detail.

Answer (score 18):

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.muted = true;
video.play()
```

Only this solution helped me, `<video autoplay muted ...>...</video>` didn't work...

Answer (score 15):

I've just get now the same issue with my video

```
<video preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="Home_Teaser.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Home_Teaser" type="video/webm">
  <source src="Home_Teaser.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

After search, I've found a solution:

If I set "preload" attributes to "true" the video start normally

Comment: The preload attribute is ignored by browser if autoplay is present.

Answer (score 15):

I had a problem when playing a video on Safari on iPhones. Adding the `playsinline` attribute in the `video` tag can solve this problem, and it works!

```html
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline class="someClass">
  <source src="source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You will also get this problem on Safari on OSX, in case you get yourself confused about this property `playsinline`, [here](https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/) is the explaination.

> Mobile browsers, `playsinline` **will play the video right where it is** instead of the default, which is to open it up fullscreen while it plays.

For the Safari on OSX, as the default websites `Auto-Play` option is `Stop Media with Sound`, this strategy can also introduce the permission issue.

That's why we need the property `muted`.

[image: Safari Preferences]

Comment: This worked for me in 2021

Comment: Still going strong in 2022.

Answer (score 12):

On safari iPhone when battery is low and iPhone is on **Low Power Mode** it won`t autoplay, even if you have the following attributes: **autoplay, loop, muted, playsinline** set on your video html tag.

Walk around I found working is to have **user gesture** event to trigger video play:

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    var allVideos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for (var i = 0; i < allVideos.length; i++) {
        allVideos[i].play();
    }
},{ once: true });
```

You can read more about user gesture and Video Policies for iOS in webkit site:

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 11):

> Try this:

```
  <video width="320" height="240"  autoplay muted>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Answer (score 10):

For angular, you'll have to mute it and play it in the `ngAfterViewInit()` like the following

```html
<video height="256" loop autoplay muted controls id="vid" #videoRef>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="video_file.mp4"></source>
         <source type="video/ogg" src="video_file.ogg"></source>
</video>
```

```js
 ​@ViewChild('videoRef', { static: true }) videoRef!: ElementRef

​ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  ​const media = this.videoRef.nativeElement
  ​media.muted = true 
  ​media.play() 
​ }
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding the below code at the bottom of the page worked for me . I dont know why it works :(

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('vid').play();
 },1000);
```

Comment: reason is because you are waiting for the video to be loaded within the buffer then you play it.

Comment: To be a bit more specific here: the code above waits for 1 second (1000ms) and then plays the video. It doesn't wait for the video to be loaded as it doesn't know when the video is done. To get the correct moment when video is loaded, one should use `document.getElementById('vid').addEventListener('loadeddata', function (){//do whatever you want});`   more details on the event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event).

Answer (score 7):

- Please use `muted` keyword before `autoplay` word, Here some privacy change at April, 2018.
- You may read policy [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 6):

We recently addressed a similar issue with an embedded video and found that the autoplay and muted attributes were not sufficient for our implementation.

We added a third "playsinline" attribute to the code and it fixed the issue for iOS users.

This fix is specific to videos that are to be played inline. From https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ :

On iPhone,  elements will now be allowed to play inline, and will not automatically enter fullscreen mode when playback begins.
 elements without playsinline attributes will continue to require fullscreen mode for playback on iPhone.
When exiting fullscreen with a pinch gesture,  elements without playsinline will continue to play inline.

Answer (score 6):

Google updated Autoplay Policy. Autoplay only work on mute mode.
Check the link https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: the video is muted, check the question

Answer (score 6):

Try swapping in 
`autoPlay` for `autoplay`.

It seems to be case sensitive at times. Very bizarre because it worked as `autoplay` for me, but only if I included `controls`

Comment: Wow, this worked for me! Did not expect that

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    <video height="256" loop autoplay controls id="vid">
     <source type="video/mp4" src="video_file.mp4"></source>
     <source type="video/ogg" src="video_file.ogg"></source>
```

This is how I normally do it. loop, controls and autoplay do not require a value they are boolean attributes.

Answer (score 5):

I got mine to autoplay by making it muted.
I think Google rules won't let chrome auto-play unless it's muted.

```
<video id="video" controls autoplay muted
        border:0px solid black;"
        width="300"
        height="300">
    <source src="~/Videos/Lumen5_CTAS_Home2.mp4"
            type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    Please download the mp4 plugin to see the CTAS Intro.
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers worked for me. 
My workaround was to trigger a click on the video itself; hacky (because of the timeout that is needed) but it works fine:

```
function startVideoIfNotStarted () {
    $(".id_of_video_tag").ready(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            videojs("id_of_video_tag").play()
        }, 1000);
    });
}
$(startVideoIfNotStarted);
```

Comment: Nothing worked on Chrome worked for me either. With the .play() fix (hack) above I was getting a "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()." in the console. There was a few other jQuery functions on the page, so thought that a timer would give Chrome enough time to sort itself out. It worked. I set a 0.5 second timer in $( document ).ready()

Answer (score 4):

Spent two hours trying all solutions mentioned above.

This is what finally worked for me:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.muted = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular 10:

```
<video [muted]="true" [autoplay]="true" [loop]="true">
    <source src="/assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: In my case, this still didn't work (Angular 11.2) in Chrome. In the code I checked the video elements `muted` value and it was still set to false. Manually changing it to `true`  fixed the issue.  

Example: 
```const videoElm = this.backgroundVideo.nativeElement as HTMLVideoElement;        videoElm.muted = true;```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked on Safari iOS until I added `playsinline` attribute to the video.

If you're using react based application it would be `playsInline`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of now chrome is preventing auto play in html5 video, so by default they will not allow auto play. so we can change this settings using chrome flag settings. this is not possible for normal case so i have find another solution. this is working perfect...
(add preload="auto")

```
<video autoplay preload="auto" loop="loop" muted="muted" id="videoBanner" class="videoBanner">
<source src="banner-video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="banner-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="banner-video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
```

```
var herovide = document.getElementById('videoBanner');
       herovide.autoplay=true;
       herovide.load();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<video onload='this.play()' src='the source' autoplay controls></video>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This answers points the core problem with autoplay of videos. The rule of thumb is that nothing on page can do sounds automatically, without prior user interaction. Muting makes autoplay on page load possible.

Answer (score 2):

iOS Safari, Safari requires us to add the playsinline attribute.

```
<video autoplay muted playsinline>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where it had something to do with the order of the different filetypes. Try to change it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I started out with playing all the visible videos, but old phones weren't performing well. So right now I play the one video that's closest to the center of the window and pause the rest. Vanilla JS. You can pick which algorithm you prefer.

```
//slowLooper(playAllVisibleVideos);
slowLooper(playVideoClosestToCenter);

function isVideoPlaying(elem) {
    if (elem.paused || elem.ended || elem.readyState < 2) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    var isVisible = elementTop < window.innerHeight && elementBottom >= 0;
    return isVisible;
}
function playVideoClosestToCenter() {
    var vids = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    var smallestDistance = null;
    var smallestDistanceI = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        var el = vids[i];
        var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var elementBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
        var elementCenter = (elementBottom + elementTop) / 2.0;
        var windowCenter = window.innerHeight / 2.0;
        var distance = Math.abs(windowCenter - elementCenter);
        if (smallestDistance === null || distance < smallestDistance) {
            smallestDistance = distance;
            smallestDistanceI = i;
        }
    }
    if (smallestDistanceI !== null) {
        vids[smallestDistanceI].play();
        for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
            if (i !== smallestDistanceI) {
                vids[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }
}
function playAllVisibleVideos(timestamp) {
    // This fixes autoplay for safari
    var vids = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        if (isVideoPlaying(vids[i]) && !isScrolledIntoView(vids[i])) {
            vids[i].pause();
        }
        if (!isVideoPlaying(vids[i]) && isScrolledIntoView(vids[i])) {
            vids[i].play();
        }
    }
}
function slowLooper(cb) {
    // Throttling requestAnimationFrame to a few fps so we don't waste cpu on this
    // We could have listened to scroll+resize+load events which move elements
    // but that would have been more complicated.
    function repeats() {
        cb();
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(repeats);
        }, 200);
    }
    repeats();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with,

```
$(window).on('pageshow',function(){
    var vids = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length;){
        vids[i].play();
    }
})
```

You have to launch the videos after the page has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is simple and short and it works with my code whereas I have the video full screen and behind other elements I simply use z-index -1;

```
    <video autoplay loop id="myVideo">
```

Answer (score 0):

In React + Chrome, it's better to import the video than give it as src to .

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import video from './videos.mp4';
const StyledVideo = styled.video`
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
object-fit: cover;
`
const BackgroundVideo = () => {
return (
    <StyledVideo autoPlay loop muted>
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
    </StyledVideo>
);
}
```

Remember

- The video is in the same directory, to import it.
- To autoplay, the video in the background, use **autoPlay** and **muted** props are there.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 15:

- This script wasn't appending the  element to the DOM on ios Safari until I added the additional appendChild method in the catch statement.

Component:

```
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer!: ElementRef;

  video_playback_error: boolean = false;

...


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
   this.playVideo();
    });
  }

playVideo() {
    let that = this;
    let v = document.createElement('video');
    v.id = 'videoElement'
    v.src = this.mp4_video_url; // we need this
    v.muted = true;
    v.autoplay = true;
    v.loop = true;
    v.preload = 'none';
    v.playsInline = true;
    v.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    v.classList.add("w-full", "desktop-sm:h-[700px]", "h-[calc(95vh-150px)]", "absolute", "top-0", "left-0", "object-cover");
    const promise = v.play();

    if (promise !== undefined) {
      promise.then(function() {
        console.log('autoplay started');
        that.videoPlayer.nativeElement.appendChild(v);
        v.muted = true;
        v.autoplay = true;
        v.src = that.mp4_video_url;

      // Automatic playback started!
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('autoplay error - attempting to play again in .mp4 | ', error);
        v.muted = true;
        v.autoplay = true;
        v.src = that.mp4_video_url;
        
        let fallback = v.play();
        if (fallback !== undefined) {
          fallback.then((_: any) => {
            
            console.log('autoplay started');
            that.videoPlayer.nativeElement.appendChild(v);
            v.muted = true;
            v.autoplay = true;
            v.src = that.mp4_video_url;
            // Autoplay started!
          }).catch((error: any) => {

            console.log('autoplay failed - falling back to image | ', error)
            that.video_playback_error = true;
          })
        } else {
          that.video_playback_error = true;
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.video_playback_error = true;
    }
  }
```

Template:

```
 <div #videoPlayer class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am writing this answer for people who are still stuck in 2024.

Cases:
**1. Everything works fine on chrome but not on safari?**

-> Possible solution : Change your battery saver setting to never. It only works in this setting! (Wth safari :/)

[image]

**2. For chrome even if you have autplay, playsinline and muted**

-> Chances are your chrome is still not setting muted to true, you need to do
oncanplay -> videoRef.muted=true. whichever frontend frame you are using!