# HTML5 Video autoplay works not properly (sound only) in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, video, autoplay

I have a HTML5-Video on my page with a webm and a mp4 sourcefile. The video player works in Firefox and Chrome when using the controls and clicking the play button. When I add the `autoplay="autoplay"` attribute to the video autoplay is working in firefox but Chrome is just showing the poster and plays the sound. When clicking the play button in Chrome the video plays but then the sound is playing two times.

I also tried to remove the autoplay attribute and force the autoplay via jQuery with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.movie')[0].play();
});
```

but that didn't help.

Anyone had the same problem and knows a working solution?

Comment: Autoplay --- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay

Comment: I know. I did that but it's not working in Chrome anyway... :(

Comment: Which specific version of chrome did you test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)