# HTML5 Video autoplay not working with slick.js

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-video, autoplay, slick.js

Rephrasing the question

HTML5 video autoplay is not working in slick.js on chrome and safari.
everthing is working fine in firefox.

Autoplay works fine outside the slick container.

I tried this:
[Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

But cant seem to get it to work.

My slick setup

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slick-hero').on('init', function (e, slick) {
        var $firstAnimatingElements = $('div.slick-hero:first-child').find('[data-animation]');
        doAnimations($firstAnimatingElements);
    });
    $('.slick-hero').on('beforeChange', function (e, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log(nextSlide);

        var $animatingElements = $('div.slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + nextSlide + '"]').find('[data-animation]');
        console.log($animatingElements.length);
        doAnimations($animatingElements);
    });
    $('.slick-hero').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 7000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        speed: 1000,
        dots: true,
        fade: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true
    });
    function doAnimations(elements) {
        var animationEndEvents = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        elements.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $animationDelay = $this.data('delay');
            var $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.css({
                'animation-delay': $animationDelay,
                '-webkit-animation-delay': $animationDelay
            });
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animationEndEvents, function () {
                $this.css({});
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**Original question:**
I cant get a simpel HTML5 video to autoplay.

everthing is peachy in Firefox.

My relatively straight forward implementation

```
<video poster="assets/video/ocean.jpg" id="bgvid" controls autoplay loop muted>
   <source src="assets/video/ocean.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="assets/video/ocean.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="assets/video/ocean.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

This doesn't work!!! the controlls work fine, but autoplay doesn't.
I tried opening it in the browser by double-clicking, via localhost and on a my own website... nothing.

The URL´s to the videos are fine, i tested them.
Im on a macbook pro using latest version of chrome and safari.
Everything works just fine in firefox.

This example works fine:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay,

This example works fine:
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Tried using this allso:
https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide/

The demo files work just fine.
But when i trie to implement it on my own code, then it just shows the poster image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

Answer (score 3):

Re-posting the answer from a related question:

After using jQuery `play()` or DOM maniupulation as suggested by the other answers, it was not still working (Video wasn't autoplaying) in the Chrome for Android (Version 56.0).

As per this [post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay) in **developers.google.com**, From Chrome 53, the autoplay option is respected by the browser, *if the video is muted*.

So using `autoplay muted` attributes in video tag enables the video to be autoplayed in Chrome browsers from version 53.

Expert from the above link:

> Muted autoplay for video is supported by Chrome for Android as of version 53. Playback will start automatically for a video element once it comes into view if both `autoplay` and `muted` are set[...]
>
> ```
> <video autoplay muted>
>     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
>     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
> </video>
> ```
>
> - Muted autoplay is supported by Safari on iOS 10 and later.
> - Autoplay, whether muted or not, is already supported on Android by Firefox and UC Browser: they do not block any kind of autoplay.

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42414895/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: @FelixSFD Sorry for that! Should i delete this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If any of the parents of this video tag in your code have any DOM manipulation on them, autoplay won't work in Safari and Chrome. Here's a similar question with answers that should help you:

[Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

Comment: Just found out that everything works fine... It´s the slick.js plug-in that´s the sinner.

When i place the video element outside the slider, everything works fine.

But im still at square one... i have no idea why it´s behaving like this.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Slick.js has a lot of DOM manipulation going on. If the video tag is a child of the carousel, Chrome and Safari won't autoplay the video. You'll have to use javascript to play the video.

Comment: My original answer to check that other question still holds true. There are several solutions in there that will probably fix your problem e.g. adding `preload="true"` to the video tag, or adding a piece of javascript to play the video on the `canplaythrough` event. Honestly, there isn't enough information in your post to help me get to a point where I can debug. Maybe set up a demo for us?