# Video auto play is not working in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

This is my code which included in page. The video is not playing in safari

```
<div class="banner-video" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<script>
   $('.banner-video').vide('videos/banner-video', {
     posterType:"jpg",
     loop: true,
     autoplay: true
   });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser

Comment: It is not working.I tried earlier

Comment: also it need to be `video(` not `vide(` i think. Are you using any third-party plugin or code something?

Comment: Third party plugin-https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working. I changed the video format.Now its working in all browser