# How to implement an overlay over a video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have a slider which allows for images and videos,

i am tryin to fix an overlay over my video on the slider
but when ever i try it the video stops playing and acts like an image with the overlay present on it
link to my page where slider exists

```
http://whitechapelandpartners.com/flex/
```

screenshot of the slide
[image]

and this what i am trying that has given me this result
credit : `http://codepen.io/icutpeople/pen/whueK`

```
 .video-container {
  position: relative;
}
video {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}


.overlay-desc {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.37);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

 <?php if($type == 'video'){?>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video  width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $row_slide['path']; ?>" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.

</video> 
<div class="overlay-desc">
        <h1>Waynes World</h1>
     </div>

    </div>

      <?php }?>
```

any help to why my video stops playing

Comment: try using z-index for overlay div

Comment: why you are not having the `autoplay` attribute in your video tag, it is there in the example that you have provided.

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: zindex what if i may ask

Comment: even after the auto play it still shws like an image but i can here the sound of the video

Comment: @solanke zindex wat, and did u try it before typing this pls

Comment: to overlay-desc selector, Give z-index:99; i hope it'll work.

Comment: try using this `$('video').get(0).play()` to play the video and explanation is given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26907606/2417602

Comment: can u gv me an implementation @vikscool am unable to get it to work, besides you can inspect the element on my page to try wat ure teachin me to use thanks

Comment: i have also noticed that it works in a pure html file, but dosent work in the boostrap file

Comment: put $('video').get(0).play(); this after your JQyery library load. because of that it's throwing error now

Comment: i have placed this after my jquery at the footer, still the same

Comment: in your browser code why autoplay attribute is missing form video tag?

Comment: $( window ).load(function() {
  $('video').get(0).play()
});

try this.

Comment: nice it works @solanke please make ur suggestion an answer so i can mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and proper way to solve it by using attribute autoplay in your video tag just like following exmaple

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Or either make it forcefully play using jquery/javascript method as follows.

```
$( window ).load(function() { $('video').get(0).play() });
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer because I can't add a comment yet.

```
z-index : # //any number
```

This determines the positioning of an element on, well it's z-line.
Think of it as a graph in algebra where 'x' will be the position left and right, 'y' will be the position up and down, and 'z' is the how much above or below and element will appear.

The default z-index is set to auto, which means it takes the z-index of it's parent. If you want to place something above it then just set the z-index to greater than the parent. You can try this very easy in the developers tools and just keep increasing the z-index until whatever you want is on top.

Or you can just go :

```
z-index: 9999999;
```

Comment: cuz iv tested it and its still the same

Comment: Yeah it is not working just by setting the z-index. Looking at the html I noticed that the <div class="video-container"> does not even go over the video player so any changes you do in the overlay-desc will appear much higher. You need to go back and chek the html and make sure all the containers work as intended.