# Why wont embedded mp4 autoplay?

Tags: html, video, mp4, autoplay

I've embedded videos into my page; I want them to have no controls, autoplay and loop. It seems to work in my code editor – Espresso. However in Chrome and Safari the first frame is still (unless I enable controls and press play).

Could anybody explain why? Code below.

```
<video class='videoplayer' autoplay="autoplay" loop preload="metadata"><source 
 src="work/2.MP4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

CSS:

```
.videoplayer {
width: 500px;
animation: 20s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser

Comment: Thank you very much