# How can youtube autoplay video with audio on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, webkit

As far as I know, HTML5  only autoplay when `muted` on safari.

However, youtube was able to autoplay video with audio.

Did youtube get exception from Safari?

How did they make it happen?

For example, if you go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dpIPeTgA64, the video will autoplay with audio.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

Comment: @TinyGiant, I'm asking how youtube is able to bypass that while I need to use 'muted' to autoplay video in HTML5. Youtube autoplay with audio on my safari browser.

Answer (score 2):

by default, safari whitelists youtube to allow autoplay. if you open youtube.com and examine preferences/websites you'll see youtube listed.