# HTML 5 Videos on my website doesnt work on Safarai

Tags: javascript, css, html

i want to get my autoplay html5 videos to work on safari too. Ive read plenty threads about that topic already but couldnt find a solution which provides functionality on both browsers.
 [Link to my website:](http://koro.moe/pages/Portfolio.html)

```
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="640" height="510">
        <source src="http://dl3.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

Comment: Take a look here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser [Duplicate]

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser

Comment: I tried multiple possible solutions but none of them worked after all, for him it didnt work on neither chrome nor safari, but for me it works everywhere besides safari.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has blocked autoplay on video in the latest version of Safari, which was announced at the WWDC 2018 alongside macOS Mojave. As a result, the `autoplay` attribute won't work on Safari.

The only way to circumvent this would be to use JavaScript to play the video. A delay of 1 second has been put in to allow time for everything to load and to improve the UX for the user.

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.play(); 
}, 1000);
```