# HTML animation intro won't start

Tags: html, css

I'm doing intro "Merry Christmas" video and I want to use HTML. 
https://cleoni.pl/

1. Chrome - didn't work
2. Firerfox - it works/didn't work
3. Opera - it works
4. Microsoft Edge - it works

```css
    #home-bg-video {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        z-index: -1;
     background: #000000;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<video id="home-bg-video" poster="../video/CHoinka_AR_001_cam_002.jpg" autoplay>
          <source src="../video/2019_choinka_dzwonki_77.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="../video/2019_choinka_dzwonki_77.webm" type="video/webm"> 
        </video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the effect you are looking for?

```css
#home-bg-video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000000;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: mymove 2s;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
}



/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
  }
  to {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
   from {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
  }
  to {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="home-bg-video" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: A nice effect:)

Comment: My animation won't turn on at all - Chrome.

Comment: I added "muted", but no sound

Comment: @Syriusz "muted" means no sound.

Comment: Looks like chrome only accepts to autoplay muted videos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser