# HTML 5 Video problems

Tags: html, css, video

I have a webpage with a full-screen html5 video (width & height 100%)
and if i open the webpage, the video does not play. But if i rightclick and then open video in new tab. then the video plays. and if i then reload my webpage then the video plays normal. I thought that was the problem but if i close my webpage and reopen it i have the same problem. Please help?

My code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"> 
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/loadingSim_icon64x64.png" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3a05f4171b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Loading Simulator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="intro.css">
    <script src="intro.js"></script> 
    </head><body onmousedown='return false' onselectstart='return false' style="cursor: none;">
      <!--<img src="./assets/loadingSimIntro.gif" width="100%" height="100%">-->
      <video autoplay class="vid" preload="auto">
        <source src="./assets/bpLoadingSimIntroFull.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

intro.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap');
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
  body {
    margin:0px;
    /*background-image: url('/assets/loadingSimIntro.gif');*/
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  .vid{
    /*position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
  }
```

Comment: note: intro.js handles only the time, so if the vid has played it continues to the next page. it has nothing to do with my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

Comment: Why you don't use videos play plugin?
They are compiled and much better...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it without a video. Its no longer needed but thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working as expected. This video will auto play.

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<video controls autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" muted>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

Comment: it does not work. i see a black box on my screen, nothing more

Comment: In Which browser you are accessing it? This code will run on all modern browsers, It is working fine in Firefox. Add **muted** attribute & try, if it works.

Comment: im using google chrome. And it worked with the mute attribute. But i need the sound too. And if i use an other audio tag then the music is not synced with the video

Comment: No don't use separate audio tag, it will not work. All you need to write javascript code to play the video with sound on initial page load, you can increase video volume through javascript.