# Why autoplay doesnt work in mobile ? reactjs

Tags: reactjs, video, jsx

i have a background video on my website (Reactjs) who doesn't work in mobile version...i tried a lot of solution but nothing is working...

First solution:

```
 <video src={video1} autoPlay muted />
```

Second solution:

```
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
            <video
              muted
              autoplay
               >
              <source src="${video1}" />
            </video>
          ` }}>
     </div>
```

And others things... i don't know what to do now..thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)

Comment: Which mobile OS did you test with (Android or iOS)?