# Why Audio Autoplay Attribute doesn't work?

Tags: html

```
<audio controls autoplay loop >
            <source src="media/Will.Smith-ft-Ludacris-Party.Starter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source src="media/Will.Smith-ft-Ludacris-Party.Starter.aac" type="audio/aac">
            <source src="media/Will.Smith-ft-Ludacris-Party.Starter.oga" type="audio/ogg">
            Youre Browser Dose Not Support Audio Tag
        </audio>
```

I'm trying with IE, Chrome, Firefox but doesn't work.

what is wrong?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser) answer your question?

Comment: You hit browser autoplay blocking of browsers. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay

Comment: thanks, @justinas its working