# How do I reference the HTML5 video element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this markup

```
<p><a href="#">LOAD VIDEO</a></p>

<video id="video" controls width="560">
    <source id="webm" type="video/webm" />
    <span>zoom-club.webm</span>
</video>
```

And this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').on('click',function(){

        var path = "../assets/" + $('span').text();

        $('source').attr('src', path);

        $('video#video').load();
        $('video#video').play();

    });

});
```

Why do I get this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This will actually work using tradition Javascript and getElementById, but for some reason the way I am referencing the video tag is broken. What gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play/pause HTML 5 video using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because

```
$('video#video')
```

gives you a jQuery object back. But it doesn't have a `play()` method.

So you need to extract the DOM object from it:

```
$('video#video')[0]
```

Now on this you can invoke `play()`:

```
$('video#video')[0].play();
```

Comment: i think `.get(0)` is better because it does not produce error if object contains no elements

Comment: Good point! But his HTML is static, how could it not contain the element? In the general case it's even NECESSARY to use get()! Thanks :)

Comment: There is no difference between [0] and get(0), both will return undefined, if the collection is empty. In fact, if you look into jQuery code, jQuery will do the exact same thing, if you pass a positive number. Beside this, jQuery has a .load and due to the fact, how this method works, it actually does invoke the native load method, altough you shouldn't use it because jQuery will also additionally dispatch a load event.