# Why doesn't creating video var from jquery work and from getElementById does?

Tags: jquery, html

It doesn't make sense to me, getElementById works just fine but I want to use jquery to keep the pattern of my website accessing elements. Any idea?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); //$("#myVideo");

        $("#btnFullScreen").click(function () {
            vid.requestFullscreen();
        });

        $("#btnPlay").click(function () {
            console.log("play");
            vid.play();
        });

        $("#btnPause").click(function () {
            console.log("pause");
            vid.pause();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: *"I want to use jquery to keep the pattern of my website accessing elements."* Why? Native JavaScript methods are alway faster than jQuery.... Also, you cannot use DOM methods on a jQuery element (that's why it doesn't work). You shouldn't convert JavaScript into jQuery for a *pattern*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play/pause HTML 5 video using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$("#myVideo");` it returns jQuery object that does not have methods like `.play` or `.pause`, in our case you need get DOM element like `$("#myVideo").get(0)`

[jQuery .get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla result is a little different compared to the JQ one: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhLhgpd/)

```
var jsDiv = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var jqDiv = $("#myVideo");

console.log(jsDiv);
console.log(jqDiv);
```

That's why your JQ solution is not working with `.play()`, as it is a JQ object and not a "pure" DOM element.

If you want to get the same result from JS and JQ, use `$("#myVideo")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If you select an object using jQuery, you get a jQuery object returned, not the actual DOM element.

Assuming there's only one `#myVideo` element on the page, you can access it like this:

```
var vid = $('#myVideo')[0];
```

or

```
var vid = $('#myVideo').get(0);
```