# Change HTML5 video button on center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there a way to change the button on the center of an HTML5 video tag? I tried positioning the container of the video and adding another absolutely positioned div inside of it with the button as a background and added a script that would trigger the play(); event and it didn't work.

Here's a screenshot: [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vHc4.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="freq-content">
    <div class="custom-play"></div>
     <video controls>
        <source src="_assets_/video/videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video> 
</div><!-- /#freq-content -->
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.custom-play').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#freq-content video').play();
});
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#freq-content{position:relative}
#freq-content video{height:750px;width:100%}
.custom-play{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:url(../images/button-play.png) center center no-repeat}
```

I want the center button to be like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTZJR.png)

Comment: Need some code to get the sense.

Comment: Hi, Pranesh. I updated my question.

Comment: You're calling `.play()` on a JQuery object, not the DOM element. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery

Comment: hey, change the button to what?

Comment: Thanks, DBS.
@Pranesh, I attached a picture of the button I want to use

Comment: You literally just need to change the image `background:url(../images/button-play.png)` to your new desired image.

Comment: That's what I did and it's now using it :)

Answer (score 0):

move custom play below the video tag:

> ```
>  <div id="freq-content">     
>       <video controls>
>          <source src="_assets_/video/videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>       </video> 
> <div class="custom-play"> </div>    </div>
> ```