# Auto pause/play on scroll Javascript autoplay video html5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to create a video gallery on html5 with JS. I have it where you can scroll left to right between muted autoplay html5 videos and the videos will play/pause when scrolled onto/away from. This works fine.

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/xaviergalllo/pen/OJQezYJ)

The problem I am running into is when a user adjusts any of the html5 controls the autopause on scroll will no longer work. I am ok with turning off user video controls but I still need a way to toggle audio on/off. I added a button for it, but even when a user toggles the audio from the button, the on scroll pause/play JS stops working.

Hopefully, this makes sense. I appreciate any help!

the autoplay/pause Jquery I have:

````
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  scroll > 300 ? myvid.pause() : myvid.play()
}) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in other question and it's work for me:

[How to play pause video on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187171/how-to-play-pause-video-on-scroll/43187701#43187701)

As DaniP said before:

You need to bind your function to the [scroll event](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and also change from `autoplay` to actually **play() - pause()**, check this example snippet:

<sub>Note: I have changed from 300 to 70 just for the example but you can keep your breakpoint as you want</sub>

```js
var myvid = $('#myVid')[0];
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  scroll > 70 ? myvid.pause() : myvid.play()
})
```

```css
body {
  background:#e1e1e1;
  height:1000px;
}
video {
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myVid" width="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I would suggest using Intersection Observers instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IbRtjez6ag

Comment: @AlexJavadi This works for me but does not fix the audio issue. When the audio of the video is toggled on/off, it no longer will auto play/pause on scroll

Comment: @XavierGallo I will check in my test lab.