# Trouble with play pause button

Tags: javascript, php, html, playback, pause

I'm realizing a play/pause button for a song list. The button is working properly, but only works with the first song of the list please checkout the issue here https://www.superbackings.com I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;

    $('.play-pause').click(function() {
        if (playing == false) {
            document.getElementById('audio').play();
            playing = true;
            $(this).text("stop sound");

        } else {
            document.getElementById('audio').pause();
            playing = false;
            $(this).text("restart sound");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the foreach

```
<table class=" table table-hover table-dark ">

                    <?php 

                    if (!$_GET) {

                        header ('Location: list.php?page=1');
                    }


                    ?>

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
                            <th>Demo</th>
                            <th>Song name</th>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Version</th>
                            <th>Request</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($tracks as $key => $listado): ?>

                            <?php 

                            $nameUrl = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $listado->name));

                            ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td style="width: 25%;"><?php echo '
                                <audio id="audio" > 
                                <source src="demos/' . $listado->demo . '" type="audio/mp4"/> 
                                </audio> 
                                <a type="button" class="play-pause" title="play/pause"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

                                '?></td>

                                <td style="width: 25%;"><?php echo $listado->name ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 25%;"><?php echo $listado->artist_name ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo '€' . $listado->precio ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $listado->tipo ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;"><a href="mailto:beth@superbackings.com?subject=Listed song request&body=Hello, I want to buy the song (<?php echo $nameUrl . ')' . ' from the artist ( ' . $listado->artist_name  . ')' . ' ID ' . $listado->id ; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">REQUEST</button></a></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php endforeach ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

You can see the issue here https://www.superbackings.com

Comment: Hello, please can you post your question in English, as you are on the English language Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ready... sorry!

Comment: The title too, please.

Comment: Even so, the description of the problem is pretty unclear and vague. You'll need to describe better what you want it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: Check this one for reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646998/play-pause-html-5-video-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: @Nicolas Can you also add how the list of multiple songs looks like?

Comment: yes.. I will add the full code now.

Comment: I'd say it's probably because of `<audio id="audio" > ` and `document.getElementById('audio').play();`.  HTML elements should have unique ids (and _need_ to when you are referencing the elements by id).  So if you actually have multiple players, then they each need to have a unique id.  In your Javascript though, it would probably be better to reference by relation to the clicked item instead of by id.

Comment: What @PatrickQ said is correct. Id's need to be unique and you generate multiple elements with the audio id in your foreach loop. Change the audio id to a class and use `$(this).sibblings('.audio').get(0).play()`

Comment: could you help me to fix it. don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Nicolas  There are multiple ways to address the issue.  It kind of comes down to personal preference.  Do you _understand_ the issue as we've explained it?  Because telling you what to do won't really help you if you don't actually understand the root issue.

Comment: No my friend I don't understand it. I am a newbye.

Comment: I mean I do understand but I don't know how to apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate the audio elements with an id in your php for loop.

`<audio id="audio" >`

Change that id to a class since id's need to be unique.

`<audio class="audio" >`

Now you have to change your script so that you stop other audio elements and start the current one. Also you can use the paused property of the audio element to check if it's paused or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var playing = false;

$('.play-pause').click(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).paused) {
      //pause all audio
      $('.audio').each(function(){
        this.pause();
      });
      //start the sibbling audio of the current clicked button, the get function gets the dom object instead of the jQuery object
      $(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).play();
      $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');

    } else {
      $(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).pause();
      $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for . your help. Is not working. Not sure why.

Comment: @Nicolas There was a typo in the siblings function. If that's not it please provide your error message.

Comment: I've taken off the extra B. But is not working neither.

Comment: Yes!!! it's working now!!!! Excellent! thank you very much!! it was the extra B.

Comment: Mark can I make you one more question? How can I change the text.() for an icon?  for example.   <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

Comment: You want to change the icon I assume?

Comment: Yes, the text for an icon. a bootstrap icon

Comment: @Nicolas It's a "font awsome" icon which you can change by changing the font awsome class. See my updated code snippet.

Comment: You're amazing Mark! thank you very much! I must learn javascript! which I will!! thanks!!!